# Rscript and Nodejs integration on Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, rscript

I am trying to build a node js app in which i call rscript to do some statistical computation and return an array with 8 elements which then i pass back to nodejs so that we can display those elements on ejs pages .

I am successfully able to do this on local host everything is working fine and even rscript is running and giving back the output, but when we try to do the same on ubuntu server we are not getiing any console.log(out) on our terminal (out is the variable which gets the output from the rscript) we get a null.

We are calling the script in localhost and server in same way as shown.

```
`console.log(data);
var out = rscript(abc.R)
.data(data.xyz,data.abc)
.callSync();
console.log(out);`
```

In the above code we get json in the data variable and it gives log as well both on local and server.

I have installed all the libraries needed like rscirpt inside nodejs using npm and have already installed R and Rstudio on my ubuntu server and installed all the libraries too which are needed to run the rscript.

The rscript is placed in same folder where my index.js is alll the ejs pages are stored in other folder which the node app is able to access and display them too.

Comment: make your question more explanatory by adding what have u done for connection and other files

Comment: What do you mean? What type of connection do u want me to show ? @AkashDubey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to deploy your R script somewhere else and then call that R script using API calls in your node server file.

One of the services that you can use to call rscript as an API in node is Algorithmia. You will just need to follow their instructions and wrap all your code inside a function. It will appear as a sample there, once you create an R project.