# Integrate R and Nodejs over Digital Ocean

Tags: r, node.js, digital-ocean

I am trying to call the R code from node js using the following code

`var out = rscript("new1.R")
   .data(data.statuses, data.search_metadata)
   .callSync();`

This code is working fine when running on local host, but i am unable to call the R code when deply this code on DigitalOcean.
There is no error, but the R code is not running as well.

Comment: Without any context it'll be hard to answer this question. Please provide more information and output to reproduce. For example, environment on your localhost and your DO instance, etc.

Comment: @ChrisHartgerink refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774554/rscript-and-nodejs-integration-on-ubuntu-server?noredirect=1#comment94400544_53774554